# How do I open and view Python PY files on Windows 10?

Tags: python

I need help on how to open Python PY files in my Windows 10. PY is a script file written in the Python programming language and I am finding it difficult to open the files on my windows 10.

Comment: With any text editor – even Notepad will do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 can open a Python PY file in up to 5 ways with the help of 5 free Python file viewer software to open Python files:

PyCharm
PyScripter
Thonny
Notepad++
Atom.
more details on this >>

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-python-py-files-on-windows-10